# Empty String Meaning

Tags: python, string

I saw this line of code :

```
return " ".join(str.split(" ")[::-1])
```

What does the empty string mean before the .join function as well as the one in the parenthesis in the split function?

Comment: The first empty " " is for `split()` the words based on empty space. Second one is for `' '.join` these words back together.

Comment: You could try to break by steps: what's happening if `string.split(' ')`

Comment: `" "` is not an empty string. It is a string with one space in it.

Comment: The documentation for *join()* will help you:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join Also be aware that *split(' ')* will lead to confusing results if the string being processed has 2 or more consecutive spaces. If you just want to split on whitespace it's just *split()*

Comment: I know it's not your code, but keep in mind it's bad practice to name variables the same as reserved keywords, built-in types, and built-in functions, e.g. `class`, `str`, `max`.

Answer (score 3):

This snippet is easier to understand if you break them into two parts.
But here is the meaning of these two *" "* (a string with *a space):*

The first empty " " is for split() the words based on empty space. Second one is for ' '.join these words back together.

Examples:

```
string = 'this is a sunny day'
words = string.split()
print(words)      # ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sunny', 'day']

# 
rev_string = " ".join(string.split(" ")[::-1])
#  day sunny a is this
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response! that clears it up